# generate month leading with zero php

Tags: php, generator

How can I generate month leading with zero like `01-12`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php for($m = 1;$m <= 12; $m++){ $month =  date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m));?>                               
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('agenda/'.$tgl[0].'/'.$m);?>"><?php echo $month;?></a></li><?php } ?>
```

the output url is still `1-12`. I want it to appear as `01-12`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `sprintf`

```
<?php echo sprintf('%02d', $month); ?>
```

in your snippet

```
<?php for($m = 1;$m <= 12; $m++): ?>    
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url("agenda/${tgl[0]}/" . sprintf('%02d', $m)); ?>">
            <?php echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m)); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

how about using `str_pad` 
It will pad the string with a character '0' to a length of 2.

```
<?php 
for($m = 1;$m <= 12; $m++) { 
  $month = str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 1):

Short and fast: (sprintf is expensive)

```
    $month = ($m = date('m')) < 10 ? '0' . $m : $m;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php for($m = 1;$m <= 12; $m++){ $month =  date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m)); if ($month < 10) $month = "0".$month; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sprintf()` you can achieve this format,

```
<?php echo sprintf("%02d",$month); ?>
```

Comment: thanks its helpful but a little correction <?php echo sprintf('%02d', $m); ?> :)

Comment: @nadysaptra : okies. It's just a logic. wherever you want you could apply. welcome

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$month = date('m',mktime(0, 0, 0, $m));  //HERE give 'm' option
```

"**m**" Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros 01 through 12